# Page functions for JavaScript Parameters?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have this JS in my aspx:

```
 var calendar = $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
                header: {
                    left: 'prev,next today',
                    center: 'title',
                    right: ''
                },
                defaultView: 'resourceNextWeeks',
                numberOfWeeks: <%# GetNumWeeks() %>,
...
```

and in my page's cs:

```
   public string GetNumWeeks()
        {
            return "2";
        }
```

But it does not do anything...

Is there another way to do it?

Thanks

Comment: Look at the generated source.

Comment: Does it compile? and are you aware of razor?

Comment: @gdoron it's probably web forms

Comment: @RenanMalkeStigliani, almost forgot its existence, damn, did you have to remember it?!

Comment: `<%#` is for databinding, `<%=` is for direct writing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try changing your code to:

```
numberOfWeeks: <% =GetNumWeeks() %>
```

Answer (score 0):

Why you use code behind. You can create another function and call the function siply 
for

```
var calendar = $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
                header: {
                    left: 'prev,next today',
                    center: 'title',
                    right: ''
                },
                defaultView: 'resourceNextWeeks',
                numberOfWeeks: GetNumWeeks() ,
...


.
.
.

function GetNumWeeks()
        {
            return "2";
        }
```

Edit:

or
You can use WebMethod

please see  [this sample :](http://encosia.com/using-jquery-to-directly-call-aspnet-ajax-page-methods/)

Comment: I think he put that 2 just as an example